# What is event.clientY?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this code and wanted to know what all those `event.client` do?

```
  document.body.ondblclick = function(){
    var dclick = false;
    if(event.clientX > 8 && event.clientX < 204){
        if((event.clientY > 88 && event.clientY < 129) ||
            (event.clientY > 129 && event.clientY < 171) ||
            (event.clientY > 172 && event.clientY < 212) ||
            (event.clientY > 213 && event.clientY < 255) ||
            (event.clientY > 256 && event.clientY < 297) ||
            (event.clientY > 297 && event.clientY < 339)){
            dclick = true;
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be attempting to detect double clicks at certain locations (coordinates) within the browser window.

Answer (score 5):

Its trying to determine if someone has double clicked the mouse on a certain part of the body.  event.clientX and event.clientY are the X-Y coordinates of the mouse.

Answer (score 2):

The event object contains information about where the click took place. `clientY` will be the distance in pixels from the top left down, and `clientX` will be the distance right from the top left.

Answer (score 1):

It's checking whether user clicks on specific coordinate

Answer (score 1):

event.clientY and event.clientX are the co-ordinates of the mouse on the page, so, if the mouse is within these

dclick is defined within the function, and it does nothing more with it, so it basically does nothing.

I could not say more without context.

Answer (score 1):

The `clientX` and `clientY` properties give the location of the click in window space: that is, without regard to scrolling. For instance, if clientX = 0 and clientY = 0, the click occurred at the top-left corner of the window.

In the future, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM) is a good javascript reference.

Also, consider sending the code this came from to The Daily WTF.

Answer (score 0):

They return the horizontal and vertical coordinates of an event. Say a mouse click ? Looking at your code I think this returns a flag as true to some other event depending on some certain areas of the screen/browser being clicked by the user. More on this here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.clientX